# How can i transfer files?

Tags: hard-drive

So i am new to ubuntu (very new) and i have been reading some articles about transfering and moving files in ubuntu system but nothing helped me much.
I have an SSD that runs ubuntu, i have 2 other Hard drives that are empty.
I have made partitions in them but i can't move files from my SSD to the other hard drives. I want my SSD to run ubuntu and only but when i download something it goes right in my SSD too, i try to move it to the others but then an error says that my access is denied. Please help me!!!

I made the partitions based on a siple youtube video with Gparted (Really quick the video guy said to wipe all data from my hard drive and use all the space for partitions)
My output using sudo parted -l is:

```
Model: ATA ST3320613AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  320GB  320GB  primary  ext4


Model: ATA SanDisk SDSSDHP1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  120GB  120GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      120GB   128GB  8504MB  extended
 5      120GB   128GB  8504MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA WDC WD5000AVDS-6 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  500GB  500GB  primary  ext4
```

Comment: How did you format partitions on your HDDs? Please [sdit] your question and add output of `sudo parted -l` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `mount` command. We will fix the permissions.

Comment: what is the exact command?, or do i have to just write mount and post the outcome?

Comment: The exact command is `mount`.

Answer (score 1):

Newly formatted linux filesystems default to their root directory being owned by root and only writable to the owner.  You can change the ownership to yourself if you want access with `sudo chown yourname /path/to/drive`.

Comment: @DhmhtrhsKaskouras, please check the green check box to accept a correct answer.